# Can you use "params" in Unity

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container, parameters, abstract-factory

I have written an abstract factory which will house a collection of concrete implementations of a a simple facory interface. I want to be able to pass in the simple factory implementations using Unity. Can I use the params keyword to allow any number of registered implementations to be passed in. So my code is:

```
public class StreamAbstractFactory : IStreamAbstractFactory
{
    private readonly Dictionary<StreamFactoryType, IStreamFactory> _streamFactoryDictionary;

    public StreamAbstractFactory(params IStreamFactory[] streamFactories)
    {
        _streamFactoryDictionary = new Dictionary<StreamFactoryType, IStreamFactory>();

        foreach (var factory in streamFactories)
        {
            _streamFactoryDictionary.Add(factory.Key, factory);
        }
    }

    public Stream Create(string path, StreamFactoryType type)
    {
        if (_streamFactoryDictionary != null)
        {
            IStreamFactory factory;

            if (_streamFactoryDictionary.TryGetValue(type, out factory))
            {
               return factory.Create(path);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Is this possible in unity? Will this just "work" if I register the different implementations in the container?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unity natively compiles C#, and all of C#. They don't choose what features to compile or not. So to answer your questions, yes the params keyword can be used within Unity.